# SQL error when none of my checkboxes are checked

Tags: c#, sql

I have functionality for all or any one of these checkboxes being checked. However, when they are all unchecked I get a SQL error saying: Incorrect Syntax near ')'. Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

```
string andOr = string.Format(" {0} (", whereAnd);
                if ((!box1)
                    || (!box2)
                    || (!box3)
                {
                    whereAnd = " AND ";
                    if (box1)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                        sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 0)");
                        andOr = " OR ";
                    }
                    if (box2)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                        sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 1)");
                        andOr = " OR ";
                    }
                    if (box3)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                        sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 2)");
                    }
                    sqlCommand.AppendLine(")");
                }
```

then it does everything else for my query.

I'm stuck at trying to determine how to handle NO boxes being checked.  Do I go outside of the first if statement and do an else if (!box1) && (!box2) && (!box3)....If so what does SQL require for me to skip these selections.

OR

Do I go inside of the if statement and after it checks for box 1, 2 and 3 do I do an else since none of these are checked.  Again, if I do this what do I need to tell SQL to not include these selections?

**EDIT**

Here is the entire SQL command

```
DECLARE @jFN NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @sFN NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @sd DateTime='2016-02-24T05:00:00'
DECLARE @ed DateTime='2016-03-25T03:59:59'
DECLARE @jFId INT
EXEC dbo.GFId @jFName, @jFId OUTPUT
DECLARE @jFDescendants TABLE(fo_id INT)
INSERT INTO @jFDescendants EXEC dbo.GetFDescendants @jFId
DECLARE @sFId INT
EXEC dbo.GFId @sFName, @sFId OUTPUT
DECLARE @sFDescendants TABLE(fo_id INT)
INSERT INTO @sFDescendants EXEC dbo.GFDescendants @sFId

    select  h.object,
            h.id,
            h.se_id,
            h.co_time,
            h.ho_time,
            h.sc_time,
            h.st_time           

            CASE
                 WHEN h.id <> 0
                    THEN j.fo_id
                 ELSE u.fo_id
            END as fo_id
            from dbo.myDB AS h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Jo AS j ON h.id = j.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Se AS u ON h.se_id = u.se_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Fo AS js ON j.fo_id = js.fo_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Fo AS ss ON u.fo_id = ss.fo_id
    )
      AND  ((h.co_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed)
     OR (h.ho_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed)
     OR (h.sc_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed)
     OR (h.st_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed)
    )
    AND (js.fo_id IN (select fo_id from @jFD)
    OR ss.fo_id IN (select fo_id from @sFD))
    ORDER BY h.co_time DESC
```

Right before the line AND  ((h.co_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed) is where this sql command goes. It will look like this if only 2 are checked:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Fo AS ss ON u.fo_id = ss.fo_id
        WHERE  ((h.object= 0) OR (h.object = 1))
          AND  ((h.co_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed)
         OR (h.ho_time BETWEEN @sd AND @ed)
    ...etc
```

Comment: I think you need to add more information so that we can understand your problem.  What are the controls that are used, what is the table that you need to update?

Comment: This code is a little messy, but one can see that you only append an `")"` if all flags are `false`. Unfortunatly, you don't show what `sqlCommand` contains before this code snippet or what happens afterwards before you execute it.

Comment: Side issue - if all of boxes 1-3 are true, then you're adding `andOr` three times, which opens 3 parentheses, but you only close it once.

Comment: Please show the _complete code_ that builds your `sqlCommand`. Otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: Regarding on how to handle the non-checked boxes - your specification does not make much sense right now. Can `h.object` have some value different from 0, 1 or 2? If yes and a box is checked, should ONLY rows matching this condition be returned, or all rows but the ones matching the two checkboxes which are NOT checked?

Comment: Based on a lot of replies asking for more information I have added the entire output of the sql command.  I displayed what this call looks like with everything being checked and when 2 out of the 3 are checked.  h.object cannot have a value different from 0,1 or 2 because they are enum types.  There are only 3 enum options that belong to h.object. If all are checked then all rows should return.  If 1 or 2 are checked then only those rows should return.  If none are checked then my goal is to have NO rows return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always add the ")" to the query. You need to refactor your logic to make it work as expected.

```
            if (box1 || box2 || box3)
            {
                var op = " AND (";
                if (box1)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Append(op);
                    sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 0)");
                    op = " OR ";
                }
                if (box2)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Append(op);
                    sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 1)");
                    op = " OR ";
                }
                if (box3)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Append(op);
                    sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 2)");
                }
                sqlCommand.AppendLine(")");
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

So I know this was not my best post. This was code that I didn't write that I had to figure out and then fix.  I haven't done a lot with ADO.NET but none the less I was able to figure out a solution to what turned out to be a very simple problem.  Here is the code that I used to do it

```
string andOr = string.Format(" {0} (", whereAnd);
                if ((box1)
                    || (box2)
                    || (box3)
                {
                    whereAnd = " AND ";
                    if (box1)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                        sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 0)");
                        andOr = " OR ";
                    }
                    if (box2)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                        sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 1)");
                        andOr = " OR ";
                    }
                    if (box3)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                        sqlCommand.Append("(h.object= 2)");
                    }
                    sqlCommand.AppendLine(")");
                }
               else
                {
                    whereAnd = " WHERE ";
                    sqlCommand.Append(andOr);
                    sqlCommand.AppendLine("(h.object IS null ");
                    sqlCommand.AppendLine("))");
                    whereAnd = " AND ";
                }
```

This will check for each box to be checked. If any are checked it will append each h.object (0, 1 or 2).  If none are checked it will jump to the if else and it will return any h.objects that are null (which I don't have any so it will return none).  I wanted to post to explain what I was looking to do since OP wasn't very clear.

Comment: Note, the condition on the "else if" is redundant: is any of the three boxes was true, then it would use the truthy branch of the if.

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying I could remove the else if and just make it an else since the only reason it would ever hit this condition is if the first condition is false which means none of the boxes are true.  Good catch. I have made this correction

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using similar structure to this:

```
        string query = @"SELECT * 
                        FROM TABLE (NOLOCK) 
                        WHERE (@pBox1 = 1 OR @pBox2 = 1 OR @pBox3 = 1) 
                        AND (@pBox1 = 0 OR (@pBox1 =1 AND h.object= 0))
                        AND (@pBox2 = 0 OR (@pBox2 =1 AND h.object= 1))
                        AND (@pBox3 = 0 OR (@pBox3 =1 AND h.object= 2))
                        ";
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pBox1", box1);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pBox2", box2);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pBox3", box3);
```

I think it is cleaner and easier to understand

Comment: Why dealing with `NULL`s? And why `(NOLOCK)`?

Comment: I dealt null value because i don't understand who is box1, and which possible values. The instruction "(NOLOCK)" do not let lock the table for other requests while the select runs

Comment: Well, since `box1` etc. are used directly as condition in the if statement it has to be a non-nullable boolean. Using nolock is dangerous, it can return inconsistent results when concurrent updates/inserts/deletes are happening, don't do that unless there is a really compelling reason to do so...! if you want to avoid locking, use snapshot isolation (optimistic concurrency).

Comment: ok, as I said "similar structure", would have to adapt according to the need. Creating the terms "where" similar to the given example, you do not need to be anticipating when you enter the "AND" or "OR" in runtime

Comment: Well, the snippet looks as if there is something else in the `WHERE` clause before the checkbox checks and therefore the `AND` is added.

Answer (score -2):

This is not an sql question.  It's a generic web development question.

When you submit an html form with checkboxes, one of two things happen.  You either get a variable with all the checked values in a comma delimited list, or, if the user does not check any boxes, you get nothing.

The lack of a variable has to be handled in the web application code.  In your case, that is c#.  How you do it depends on your specific requirements.